# atanh arc-hyperbolic tangent function missing in MS Visual C++

Tags: c++, math

I am working with some code that was previously compiled on Linux with gcc compiler, and when compiling it with MS Visual C++ 2008 the math.h doesn't appear to include all the same functionality, specifically the (inverse) arc-hyperbolic tangent *atanh* function.

I've tried including math.h, cmath, using std::atanh, and didn't find much else with a google/MSDN search. Is there a simple header file available that I can include that has this?

> error C3861: 'atanh': identifier not found

Comment: `atanh` wasn't included in the C++ standard library until C++11, and MSVC 2008, understandably, doesn't include much, if any, C++11 functionality.  Can you upgrade to MSVC 2012?  Because it's included there.  Otherwise, try [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/boost/math/special_functions/atanh.hpp).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what is and what is not included in the various versions of the maths libraries.

```
Function  POSIX  old ISO  ISO C99  Microsoft(2008)  
acos      Y      Y        Y        Y     
acosh     Y      N        Y        N    
asin      Y      Y        Y        Y     
asinh     Y      N        Y        N    
atan      Y      Y        Y        Y     
atan2     Y      Y        Y        Y     
atanh     Y      N        Y        N
```

Can you not implement your own functions using the formulae:

```
    asinh(x) = log(x + sqrt(x2 + 1))
    acosh(x) = log(x + sqrt(x2 - 1))
    atanh(x) = (log(1+x) - log(1-x))/2
```

e.g.

```
float atanh (float x)
{
   //implements: return (log(1+x) - log(1-x))/2
}
```

Comment: Change "Microsoft" to "MSVC 2008", because the current edition supports all those functions.

Comment: I did end up making the function myself per your suggestion. Once again it's one of those strange cases where the library is just missing things that you would expect to be there. Anyone know why that happens? I mean, who is deciding to omit families of functions from these libraries?

Comment: Microsoft is known to implement its own C++ libraries, this includes functions for strings and maths, especially before the C++11 standard has come out. If you find the answer useful, please vote up or tick as correct.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atanh), atanh was introduced in C++11. Since C++11 was introduced in 2011, you probably can't use it in VS 2008.